# In html, check one checkbox from 2 checkbox without JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, checkbox

I'm having 2 checkbox. I need to check any one. I know using with [`Jquery`, it's easy](http://jsfiddle.net/karsho/jFG4f/). But any default option in HTML. I'm having exactly 2 checkbox.

thanks.

code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="foo" />
```

And any option to change the height and width of check box? like css.

Comment: @vinodadhikary my requirement is diff. i'm having only 2 checkbox. and i dont want Jquery. also i need some css helps.

Comment: What does `Wt` mean?  Why do you have `jquery` tag in your question if you didn't want jQuery?

Comment: I posted with JQuery and i dont want Jquery. That's why i tagged Jquery.

Comment: Guys, Are you hearing me? Why you marked as duplicate? @vinodadhikary is the 1st person, who mark as Duplicate. But he got my point from my comments. Just review my questin...

Answer (score 2):

Hi in HTML use radio button.,.... simple alterantive..less code..which improves performance as well..optimized solution

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="1">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="2">
</form>
```

Comment: @karsho if its the rt approach dnt forget to mark as answer..

Answer (score 1):

If you can use radio button which looks like checkbox.
Try this..

HTML

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="foo"  />
<input type="radio" value="2" name="foo"  />
```

CSS

```
input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;
    -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
    -o-appearance: checkbox;      /* not currently supported */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want select both check box at a time then remove `name` property in syntax.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
 <input type="checkbox" value="2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
input
{
    width: xpx;
    height: xpx;
}
```

To check one use the attribute checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="foo" checked />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be good enough

```
var $inputs = $('input');
$('input').change(function() {
    if(this.checked)
        $inputs.not(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8mZWb/3/)**

This should work no matter the number of checkboxes.

**Vanilla JS**

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    checkboxes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === 'checkbox') {
        checkboxes.push(inputs[i]);
        inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
                    if (checkboxes[j] !== this) {
                        checkboxes[j].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**[Vanilla Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8mZWb/4/)**